# Unable to understand how to solve piecewise composition of two functions

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x  & ; x < 0 \\
\sqrt{x} & ; 0 \leq x \leq 1  \\
(x-1)^2+1 & ; x > 1
\end{cases}
$$
$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2  & ; x \leq 1 \\
1 &; x > 1
\end{cases}
$$
Hello, 
firstly I would like to thank everyone who is reading this post. I need to say, that I already read all of the similar titles and tried to understand why the solution is such and what steps you need to take to get to that solution. However, I can't solve this problem on my own. all I am trying to do is composition of $f(g(x))$.

What I think I should be doing is: firstly look at what happens with $x \leq 1$ in $g(x)$. Then I input $g(x)$ which in case of $x\leq1$ is $x^2$ into $f(x)$.
After I do that I am pretty much lost on what to do, let alone the fact I don't understand what ranges to write down for particular $f(g(x))$.

I am not an native speaker, as you can probably tell, but I hope the one reading this question can understand it enough to help me.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Try to find the _range_ of $g(x)$ on each interval where it's defined. What does that imply on the domain of $f(g(x))$?

Comment: Similar question, might be helpful. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317416/502324

Comment: @big-lion Hey, I still need help.

Comment: Sure. What have you tried so far? What did you achieve? Did you understand what me and Bill hunter?

Comment: @big-lion I posted what I did so far bellow? if you can't see I am actually trying to solve it for gof atm.

Comment: @big-lion Should we move conversation to somewhere else? so we start fresh?

Answer (score 1):

As big-lion hinted:

- Start by finding the values of $x$ where $g(x)<0$; those where $0\leq g(x)\leq 1$ and those where $g(x)>1$.
- Then, replace $y$ by the value of $g(x)$ in the expression of $f(y)$.

Give it a try and show us what you come up with if you need help.

Comment: Something like this if I understood correctly?$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2(g(x))  & ; g(x) < 0 \\
\sqrt{g(x)} & ; 0 \leq g(x) \leq 1  \\
(g(x)-1)^2+1 & ; g(x) > 1
\end{cases}

Comment: I need help. I am lost on what to do or how to proceed. @bill-oharan

Comment: That's the spirit but then, what is $g(x)<0$ in terms of $x$? And what is $2g(x)$ then?

Comment: @bill-oharan Well if I take x = 1 and I input it as g(1), then I get x^2 which is always positive right? then I have to input that x^2 into f(x^2) which I can only use it in (x^2-1)^2+1 since the range is 0 <= x <= 1. Probably is incorrect but that is how I think.

Comment: Ok but that is not what I asked. For what values of $x$ do we have $g(x) <0$?

Comment: ohh, I don't know if I understand corrently but for every negative x input in g(x), values should be positive. @bill-oharan

Comment: That is right! But then what happens for positive $x$?

Comment: @bill-oharan Well I would say it's stays at 1 to infinity? kinda constant 1?

Comment: That's for $x\geq 1$ so we are closing in: what about $0\leq x\leq 1$?

Comment: @bill-oharan well for x in between 0 and 1 g(x) = x^2

Comment: Then what is the sign of $g(x)$?

Comment: amm meaning by what the y is? Well it's always positive expect when 0 then it's 0. it never goes into negative

Comment: Precisely! Now you know when $g(x)<0$ (as you noticed that is never the case). Now you may do the same thing to know when $g(x)>1$.

Comment: well when g(x) > 1 then it's going to infinity for every x < -1? is that what you meant?

Comment: Indeed. Now, we know that $g(x)<0$ never happens, $0\leq g(x) \leq 1$ when $x\geq -1$ and $g(x)>1$ when $x <-1$. Then $$f(g(x))=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{g(x)} & ; x \geq -1  \\
(g(x)-1)^2+1 & ; x < -1
\end{cases}
$$ Do you agree?

Comment: yeah I agree with what you said above, but this isn't over yet right?

Comment: Not just yet. What is left is to replace $g(x)$ with the right value. What is $g(x)$ when $x\geq -1$ and when $x< -1$?

Comment: g(x) = x^2 for x >= -1 same for x < -1

Comment: No. Read the definition of $g$ again

Comment: @bill-oharan I am actually lost now. didn't we agree that g(x) for x >= -1 is x^2 to 0 and then x^2 to 1 which is constant? We also find out that for x < -1 our g(x) behaves as x^2 to infinity?

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. Please do read the question and my comment about the values of $f\circ g$ again and tell me what is not clear.

Comment: you mean this one? f(g(x))?

Comment: This one: $$f(g(x))=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{g(x)} & ; x\geq -1  \\
(g(x)-1)^2+1 & ; x < -1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I mean, We agreed on the behaviour of our g(x) for g(x)<0 then 0≤g(x)≤1 and finally g(x)>1

Comment: No I never intended to mention how $g(x)$ behaved before the comment I mentioned.

Comment: ohh I think I see where I misspoke. I thought we were inputing g(x) into ranges of f(x).

Comment: Ok. Does it seem any clearer to you now?

Comment: until this point yes, however proceeding is not going to go well I believe.

Comment: Again, if [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833631/unable-to-understand-how-to-solve-piecewise-composition-of-two-functions/2833653?noredirect=1#comment5845286_2833653) is clear to you, the end is near. What is the expression of $g(x)$ for $x<-1$?

Comment: I know how we reached this point, however.. now I think I am wrong when I think that I need to look at g(x) definition and it's ranges? by doing that, I would say g(x)=x^2, but you said that was wrong right?

Comment: It is wrong. $g$ is defined piecewise. That's why you have to take a closer look at the ranges

Comment: @bill-oharan g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2  & ; x \leq 1 \\
1 &; x > 1
\end{cases} isn't this definition of g?

Comment: Yes but now I am asking you what is $g(x)$ for $x<-1$ and what is $g(x)$ for $x\geq -1$ using that very definition.

Comment: Looking at the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=piecewise%5B%7B%7B%5B%2F%2Ffunction:x%5E2%2F%2F%5D,%5B%2F%2Frange:-infinity%3Cx%3C1%2F%2F%5D%7D,+%7B%5B%2F%2Ffunction:1%2F%2F%5D,%5B%2F%2Frange:x%3E1%2F%2F%5D%7D%7D%5D) might help.

Comment: @bill-oharan yes g(x) for x < -1 is positive as it's kinda x^2? and g(x) for x >= -1 is x^2 graph to untill 1 and then constant 1. but this is what I said earlier I am afraid.

Comment: Then sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: Now replace $g(x)$ by its actual value in the expression of $f\circ g$ we got and you are done.

Comment: Aha, so watching that definitions of FoG or g(x) should I input the right g(x) value?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean but give it a go and we'll see.

Comment: f(g(x))= \begin{cases} \sqrt{x^2} & ; x \geq -1  \\ (x^2-1)^2+1 & ; x < -1 \\ 1 & ; x>1 \end{cases} I must say I am not sure about the ranges I used?

Comment: Seems fine to me. Now, you may notice (though that is for you to decide what is best) that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. Try to put all that we did in an answer of your own so future readers won't have to read our whole discussion. That way, things might also seem clearer to you.

Comment: @bill-oharan I must thank you for being so patient with me! I mean this was just... no words :D However If I check my solutions I get some errors vs. our answer.

Comment: f(g(x))= \begin{cases} \ |x| & ; -1 \leq 0 \leq 1  \\ (x^2-1)^2+1 & ; x < -1 \\ 1 & ; x>1 \end{cases}

Comment: You are very much welcome. What is the solution you've been given?

Comment: @bill-oharan I posted my solution above your comment.

Comment: I guess it is $-1\leq x \leq1$ rather than $-1\leq 0 \leq1$. Now the only difference is that they included  $x \leq1$ in the first case which you did not. They are thus more precise because from a strictly logic point of view,  $-1\leq x$ and $x>1$ share quite a lot of values of $x$. Their solution is better because it is more accurate but I think you understood that in the same way.

Comment: @bill-oharan Thanks for guiding me untill this solution, now I will try to do it alone for gof and then get back to you ok?

Comment: OK. But please do add an answer of your own when you're finished :)

Comment: @bill-oharan yes of course I will construct something appealing for the one just looking for answer :)

Comment: @bill-oharan I set up gof as so: \begin{cases} \ (f(x))^2 & ; f(x) \leq 1  \\ 1 & ; f(x) > 1 \end{cases}

Comment: I guess now I have to imagine how f(x) function looks for <= 1 and > 1 ?

Comment: Yes! That is correct.

Comment: @bill-oharan should i draw f(x) graph first? or how would you do it? or should I look at piecewise fx definition?

Comment: Personally I'd just use the definition but if the graph helps you, use it.

Comment: so for for x in range 0 <= x <= 1 the f(x) is positive. Then for every x < 0 the f(x) is negative to infinity. Also for x > 1; f(x) is positive. Now what does that tell me?

Comment: Here the sign of $f$ does not tell you anything. You have to find the values of $f$ where $f(x)\leq 1$ and those where $f(x)>1$.

Comment: @bill-oharan \begin{cases} \ (f(x))^2 & ; x \leq 1  \\ 1 & ; x = 1 \end{cases} I asked myself: for what values of x do we have f(x)

Comment: @bill-oharan \begin{cases} \ 4x^2 & ; x \leq 1  \\ x & ; x <= 1 \\ 1 & ; x =1 \end{cases} I got something like that. Also you said above sign doesn't mean nothing here, did it have  a meaning in fog only because it was in the required range?

Comment: You have the right values but not the right ranges. You could have noticed that because your first and second cases have the same range. Also, what happens for $x>1$? I talked about sign earlier because we were discussing whether $g(x)>0$ or not which is exactly the definition of the sign of $g$. But now we are not dealing with $0$ but $1$ as you noticed.

Comment: @bill-oharan for x > 1 f(x) goes to infinity.

Comment: Okay but what is the value of $g\circ f(x)$ for $x>1$?

Comment: well the primary value was set to 1 I believe. I speak about this: \begin{cases} \ (f(x))^2 & ; f(x) \leq 1  \\ 1 & ; f(x) > 1 \end{cases}

Comment: I am not sure you get it right so let's take it step by step as we did with $f\circ g$: $f$ actually has a nice "property" when on each interval where it is defined piecewise, $f(x)$ is in the same interval as $x$. What I mean is that $x<0 \Leftrightarrow f(x)<0$; $0 \leq x\leq 1 \Leftrightarrow 0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ and $x>1 \Leftrightarrow f(x)>1$. Try to think about this.

Comment: @bill-oharan Yes, I may be doing it wrong :(. Let's take it step by step.

Comment: @bill-oharan I was busy last couple of days, so I couldn't proceed with this problem. I still am stuck on gof. I need to understand this, and could you tell me if this video is of any help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1R8mSnN8no

Comment: so step by step, I have this:
{ (f(x))21;f(x)≤1;f(x)>1
. Now I should input and test every available option from f(x) right? So for example:
{ (2x)21;2x≤1;f(x)>1
which I can then find out that x for 2x^2 \leq 1/2 and x for 1 x \g 1. but now, I need to look if it's in range right? but which range do I test x<=1/2 and x>1/2 with g(x):x<=1 or f(x):x<0

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand your comment, please see [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting (it may be useful for future posts too).